# SoapUI SSO using Kerberos

Tags: single-sign-on, soapui, kerberos

I've been trying to use Single Sign On Kerberos through SoapUI (version 5.2.1). I've been through a lot of forums and topics about it and I can't seem to find any successful solution. I'm kind of new to soapUI and I'm finally coming here to find some help

The two main solutions I tried are the following :

1. Add a new authorization SPNEGO/Kerberos to my soap request and enter the credentials. The issue I have is that the request has a header containing locale (for the language), username and password. When I try to use kerberos in the request directly, whether the request fails because I leave the username and password blank in the header and just fill them in in the added Kerberos authorization thus having a response telling me that I entered bad username or password, or the request is filled in with the authentification informations and uses them (so no sso connection).

The header goes as follows :

```
<soap:Envelope ...>
  <soap:Header>
    <soap1:locale>en_US</soap1:locale>
    <soap1:authentication>
      <soap1:username></soap1:username>
      <soap1:password></soap1:password>
    </soap1:authentication>
  </soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
</soap:Body>
```

2.I begin my test suite with an HTTP request using kerberos and having my wsdl as an endpoint. The system seems to take my authorizations information but I get an xml parsing error and I don't know why. I'm joining the HTTP request as a screenshot (https://i.stack.imgur.com/2W5Al.png). And here is the response I get :

```
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
   <soap12:Fault>
    <soap12:Code>
     <soap12:Value>soap12:Receiver</soap12:Value>
    </soap12:Code>
    <soap12:Reason>
      <soap12:Text xml:lang="">gw.xml.XmlException: Unable to parse XML from input stream at line 1 column 1</soap12:Text>
    </soap12:Reason>
    </soap12:Fault>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

If that can help, I'm working with Guidewire exposed webservices.

I hope I gave enough information

Many thanks in advance

P.S. : I tried to add a "Hello" sentence at the beginning of my post but, stackoverflow won't accept it :)